# Can not find ClipperOffset class C#

Tags: c#, clipperlib

Good afternoon,
I downloaded NuGet package Clipper for C# -
[Clipper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clipper/).
In examples, I saw is used a ClipperOffset class, for example, in this topic:
[Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492416/confused-on-clipper-in-c-sharp), [Example2](https://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/discussion/1148419/thread/7b8268d5/).
But I did not find this class. I see only Clipper, ClipperBase classes. I am confused. How can I find ClipperOffset class?

Comment: Please provide more information. Kindly put the link to your NuGet package and a link to the example you are following.

Comment: Sorry, I added the link to this package

Comment: Have you added class reference ?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to be there in 6.4. It is there in 6.2.10, and in [the SourceForge code](https://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/C%23/clipper_library/clipper.cs#l4432). It's probably worth contacting the project maintainers through NuGet and asking them.

Comment: If you install Clipper 6.2.10, as per Example 2, you'll find ClipperOffset. If you install 6.4, the latest, you will not. Apparently the API has changed.

Comment: Perfect! So, this functionality will not be supported in future versions?

Comment: We don't know sorry - you'll have to ask the maintainers. It seems more likely to me they've renamed it rather than dropping the functionality, or 6.4 could just be a bad build for whatever reason.